# Erlang, Is it possible to reload or upgrade a nif library without restart the shell?

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I have a nif library and every time i recompile it, I must restart the shell to reload or upgrade this library.

Here is my erlang code:

```
-module(q4).
-export([init/0]).

-on_load(init/0).


init() ->
    erlang:load_nif("./q4_nif", reload).
```

Every time i compile the erlang module, this error occurs:

```
`The on_load function for module q4 returned {error,
                                         {upgrade,
                                          "Upgrade not supported by this NIF library."}}`
```

and when i call `init/0` function, this error occurs:
`{error,{reload,"Reload not supported by this NIF library."}}`

Is there anyway to fix this problem and load new nif library without restarting the shell?

Comment: Erlang/OTP 20.0-rc1: "The NIF library reload is not supported anymore." FYI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need to provide an `upgrade` function in your NIF, which you specify in your call to `ERL_NIF_INIT`:

```
ERL_NIF_INIT(MODULE, ErlNifFunc funcs[], load, reload, upgrade, unload)
```

The upgrade function is documented in the [`erl_nif` man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html).

Comment: I filled this arguments and above errors fixed but still erlang vm not loads new nif version and uses the older version.

Comment: In an Erlang 17 or 18 shell, when I reload an Erlang module, call it `foo` for example, that uses `on_load` to load a NIF, the upgrade function in the NIF runs. Type `l(foo). or `c(foo).` in the shell and the upgrade function is invoked and everything reloads properly, which is exactly what should happen. If you're seeing "reload not supported" errors, this means you're calling a function in your already-loaded Erlang module that is then trying to reload your NIF, and you shouldn't do that. Make sure your NIF has an upgrade function, and use `l(your_module).` to reload both the module and NIF.

Answer (score 2):

#### **UPDATE** Root cause found

**It appears `delete` must called *twice* before hot-reloading NIFs.** This seems like a erlang bug.

```
force_upgrade_module(Mod) ->
  true == code:purge(Mod),
  true == code:delete(Mod),
  code:purge(Mod),
  code:delete(Mod),
  {module,Mod} == code:load(Mod).
```

Even with implementing `upgrade` in `ERL_NIF_INIT`, there are still some issues that may or may not be platform-specific. For example, on macOS: feel free to delete the `priv/{{module}}.so` after calling `load_nif` in the erlang stub module and it will just continue silently succeed and not really reload the NIF .so.